# Blender's structure, folders, subfolders, files, modules. What is a best turorial on that and where to find it

Tags: edit-mode, customization, documentation

I'm new to blender structure and coding, I have played around with blender before, nothing serious, just designing things in 3d view with the mouse and using some textures to coat things. I have done that a lot but that is about it.

To learn blender very good I think one should start with blender's directory structure, what each folder does as in purpose, what is it's files, what get's copied where and how, how to move things around in folders, where blender stores things and so on. I'm already getting lost in blender's directory and file's structure. There is no video tutorial on this  anywhere ?

I mean where blender installs things, where it keeps it's paths, the file structure how it links up to the blender engine and functionality.

I get installation errors for example and because I don't understand the structure I may not know what is the main cause, once a person understands blender's file system structure it is easier to solve problems,

Is there any good tutorial on the whole overview of things, everyone has tutorial on 3d modeling or scripting api but there is lack on this.

It would be nice to see such tutorial for example on youtube that is an hour long maybe, or something similar somewhere else in text form.  I find blender's documentation from blender site to say the least grouchy and very robotic without much explenation.

Any good tutors on this that anyone may know ?